# Facebook - Create apprequests for test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to include facebook app invites in my automated integration tests. Is it possible to create a user-to-user apprequest for facebook test users with the graph api?

Posting to /{user_id}/apprequests with a 'message' and a 'to' parameter seems to create an app-to-user apprequest and ignores the 'to' parameter.

Comment: Invites can not be send via API, they need to be send via the dialog.

Comment: Is there an other way to test apprequests programmatically?